# How do I find the greatest digit in a number? Racket

Tags: racket

```
(define hmaxDigit 
  (lambda (n b)
    (cond
      ((< n 10) n)
      ((> n (* 10 b)) (hmaxDigit n (* b 10)))
      ((< 10 (remainder b))
       ((> (quotient n b) (remainder n b)) (quotient n b))
       ((< (quotient n b) (remainder n b)) (remainder n b)))))
```

This is what I have, but it only works with 2 digit numbers.

Comment: outputs the greatest digit in an integer

Answer (score 1):

```
If n<10 then n is the_maximum_digit
else the_maximum_digit is the maximum of 
                               the first_digit and 
                               the maximum of the remaining digits.

(define (maximum-digit n)
  (cond
    [(< n 10) n]
    [else     (max (first-digit n) (maximum-digit (remaining-digits n)))]))
```

Details such as `first-digit` and `remaining-digits` needs to be filled out.